# List comprehension with If vs If else

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The third list comprehension `lst3` doesn't work when the `for` statement is written first. I am trying to understand why `lst3` doesn't work similarly as `lst1`...

```
lst1 = [i for i in range(20) if (i % 2 == 0) if (i % 3 == 0 ) if (i% 12 ==0)  ]
print(lst2)


lst2 = [i if (i % 2 == 0) else "odd" for i in range(20)]
print(lst2)

lst3 = [i for i in range(20) if (i % 2 == 0) else "odd" ]
print(lst3)
```